# Unable to move or remove files from Desktop on Mac OS Catalina

Tags: macos, file-permissions, macos-catalina

I am having an issue with the Desktop folder on my MacBook. I am not able to move or remove files from my Desktop using the GUI.

I have tried the following steps:

- `cmd` + `backspace` on a file: Nothing happens, except that the selection changes to the next file. No error is shown.
- Right click a file and select 'Move to bin.': Nothing happens. No error is shown.
- Drag a file from Desktop to another folder: Nothing happens. No error is shown.
- `cmd` + `x` on a file and `cmd` + `v` on another folder: The file is copied to the new folder, but the original file is still there.

It doesn't matter if I perform these actions on the actual Desktop or from a Finder window.

---

At first I thought it was a permissions error, however:

- `rm` or `mv` commands do work as expected.
- `ls -l` produces the following output: `drwxr-xr-x@ 32 my-user  staff 1024 Mar 12 10:22 Desktop`

---

Right now I'm a bit puzzled. I have a suspicion that it's an issue with iCloud Drive, since I've had problems on another Mac in the past as well, where I couldn't open files on my Desktop.

On this Mac I disabled the syncing of my Desktop folder to my iCloud drive. I thought maybe that caused the issue, so I tried re-enabling and disabling it again, which caused all my files to be removed from the Desktop at once, but I still couldn't remove any files myself, not with iCloud Drive enabled, nor with it disabled.

Are there any other steps I can take to resolve this issue?

Comment: By any chance do you have iCloud on and turned on Desktop? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206985

Comment: I used to, but I turned it off. RIght now, it doesn't change anything if I turn it on or off.